# Limiting created coupons to an email address with AutomateWoo plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I'm using an [AutomateWoo](https://automatewoo.com/docs/variables/personalized-coupons/?utm_source=variable-description&utm_medium=plugin&utm_campaign=plugin-links) workflow to generate a coupon on certain triggers, the triggers work fine.

As the action, I'm sending an email and using the following to generate a coupon. Again this works fine and it generates the coupon based on the template.

```
   {{ advocate.generate_coupon | template: 'raf-advocate', prefix: 'raf-advocate-' }}
```

Is there a way to limit the created coupon to an email address? I can use the variable in AutomateWoo `{{ customer.email }}` to get the email address.

I've also tried the following but I can't work out if you can limit it to an email address:

```
{{ customer.generate_coupon | template: 'raf-advocate' }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this helps anyone, you can set a filter in your functions.php file to limit it to an email address (in this case it takes the email that you're sending the email to).

```
add_filter( 'automatewoo/variables/coupons/use_email_restriction', '__return_true' );
```